# File upload Capacitor Js

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, capacitor

I am using Capacitor Js & React Js so I can export the app to android, iOS and web without having separate code bases. The problem that I am facing is with uploading a video, I have no idea on how to keep the video upload running once the user exits the application the problem should be solved for android and iOS. If someone has an idea on how to do it please let me know. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need a Capacitor or Cordova plugin to implement this functionality.

You could try the following plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-upload

Comment: As far as I have seen something similar it was called background tasks the thing with that is that it will run once the app has been putted on the background, I will take a look at the link you provided. Thank you